# Check if ALL the update operations resulted in modification in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was following this [article on using transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-implement-transactions) over multiple collections with MongoDB and nodejs. After much trying and failing, I found that, transaction only works with ReplicaSet. So I've decided to modify my schema so that I can work with single document updates.

My schema sort of looks like this,

```
// collection "products"
{
  shop: 'ShopID1',
  customer: ['CustomerID1', 'CustomerID2'],
  products: [
    {product: 'ProductID1', productCount: 10, customer: ['CustomerID1']} ....
  ]
}
```

So, basically, when a `customer` buys a `product`, I want to decrease its `productCount` and add them to both the specific products `customer` array and the shops customer array. A customer can only buy a product if its count is >0. Another constraint is that, a customer can buy only **ONE** product from a shop.

I have figured out the following update query for this,

```
db.collection('products').updateOne(
        { shop: shopName},
        { 
            $inc: {'products.$[elem].productCount': -1},
            $addToSet: {
                'products.$[elem].customers': customerId,
                'customers': customerId,
            },
        },
        { 
            arrayFilters: [ {"elem.product": productId, "elem.productCount": {$gt: 0}} ],
        },
    );
```

This update operation works in a valid scenario (Product is available and customer has not yet purchased anything from the shop). But it will fail in invalid scenarios.

One way I can check the the purchase is valid is to check if each individual update resulted in a modification. Is there any way to check if each of the 3 update operations were successful and if not somehow revert the update? I would also appreciate alternative suggestions to handle this scenario. Thanks.

Note: I am using MongoDB 4.4 server and accessing it using the mongo client 3.6 via NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

updateOne returns the number of changed documents.

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.products.updateOne(         { shop: 'shopName'},         {              $inc: {'products.$[elem].productCount': -1},             $addToSet: {                 'products.$[elem].customers': 'customerId',                 'customers': 'customerId',             },         },         {              arrayFilters: [ {"elem.product": 'productId', "elem.productCount": {$gt: 0}} ],         },     );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Comment: Yes it does. But I need to know number of updated "fields". If one of the fields is not updated then I would consider it as an invalid operation.this implementation is super janky as I'm starting to learn mongo. I'll be thinking of a better modeling to handle this scenario

Comment: Everything you provided in the update document, or as update operators, is written into the database if the find condition is satisfied.

Comment: Yes. I think the find condition I've specified is not entirely correct. I tried with elemMatch and it provided better response.